# Open a URL in Chrome using Java in Linux and MAC

Tags: java, linux, macos, google-chrome, command-line

How to start chrome using Java?

For Windows the code is just as simple as below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start chrome http://localhost:8080"});
```

Is there something like above?

Comment: And what do you want it to do if the user does not have Chrome installed?

Comment: Will catch the exception like nothing happened!. This is the first step. In the next step I will check on trying different browser if one fails.

Answer (score 5):

In Linux you can use like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "/path/to/chrome http://yourwebsite.com"});
```

Replace the /path/to/chrome with the path in your system. Generally Google Chrome is installed at /opt/google/chrome/chrome

Or you can use google-chrome like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "google-chrome http://yourwebsite.com"});
```

If you want to open up in chromium browser in Linux use it like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "chromium-browser http://yourwebsite.com"});
```

For MAC OS try like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open", "-a", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app", "http://yourwebsite.com/"});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try these.

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine for ubuntu 15.10 or higher

```
    String[] cmd = {"bash","-c","google-chrome www.yourUrl.com"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Selenium.

   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Check here (Note: Java File is Compiled and run by commands on Terminal)  
     File name: Test.java  

     public class Test {  
          public static void main(String[] args) {  
             try {  
                   System.out.println("Executing command to open a chrome tab with terminal command!");  
                   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "google-chrome https://stackoverflow.com/"});  
                   System.out.println("A New tab or window should get opened in your Chrome Browser with Stack Overflow website!");  
                 } catch (Exception ex) {  
                     ex.printStackTrace();  
                 }  
          }  
     }  

/**here
     google-chrome https://stackoverflow.com/ -> terminal command to open a new chrome tab or window with the stack-overflow website.
**/
```